# Windows 8: Issue with server running on windows 8 and running an application on the same windows 8 PC

Tags: windows-8

I am trying to run a server on windows 8 and running an application on the same windows 8 PC.
The application is given the IP of the PC so that it connects to this server, but the connection doesn't happen.
But if I run the server and the application from 2 different windows 8 PCs, it works fine.

My application is trying to connect to the XMPP server through this service daemon server(acts like a intermediate proxy server)

What could be the reason? Is it some setting issue ?

Below are the logs:

```
'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'D:\LIBRA_WINRT_REL_V_0_1\RAClient_Intf_8_10_12 \Debug\sample_app\AppX\sample_app.exe'. Symbols loaded.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

 'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.VCLibs.110.Debug_11.0.50522.1_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\vccorlib110d.d     ll'. Symbols loaded.

 'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

 'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.VCLibs.110.Debug_11.0.50522.1_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\msvcp110d.dll'    . Symbols loaded.

 'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.VCLibs.110.Debug_11.0.50522.1_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\msvcr110d.dll'     . Symbols loaded.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

The thread 0x4dc has exited with code 0 (0x0).

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ninput.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wininet.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d11.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinTypes.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\urlmon.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\UIAutomationCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\twinapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\iertutil.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dxgi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SHCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptsp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rsaenh.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\actxprxy.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.UI.Immersive.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dui70.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\DWrite.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d2d1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MrmCoreR.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\BCP47Langs.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\profapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.UI.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msftedit.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.Globalization.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dxgidebug.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d10warp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

 'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\igd10umd32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

 'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dcomp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

The thread 0x84c has exited with code 0 (0x0).

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crypt32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msasn1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

   'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dpapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

  'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'D:\LIBRA_WINRT_REL_V_0_1\RAClient_Intf_8_10_12\Debug\sample_app\AppX\ra.dll'. Symbols loaded.

  [17:33:7(f0c)ALL ]Faile to Create a log file ( C:Users estDocumentsVisual Studio 2012ProjectsRAClient_IntfDebug\test_re_2012-10-29T17-33-07.log )

  [17:33:7(f0c)ALL ]

  [17:33:7(f0c)ALL ] +-------------------------------------------+

  [17:33:7(f0c)ALL ] | < libra > |

  [17:33:7(f0c)ALL ] | Vesion : 1.2.5+b |

  [17:33:7(f0c)ALL ] | Date : Apr 17, 2012 |

  [17:33:7(f0c)ALL ] +-------------------------------------------+

  [17:33:7(f0c)ALL ]

 'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\threadpoolwinrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

[17:33:10(f0c)ALL ]Logging in as (test@example.com)

[17:33:10(f0c)ALL ]XMPP Server : 107.108.82.145:5222

[17:33:10(f0c)ALL ]Stun Server : 107.108.72.62:3474

[17:33:10(f0c)ALL ]Turn Server : 107.108.72.62:3474

[17:33:10(f0c)ALL ]Turn ELB Server : 107.108.72.62:3474

[17:33:10(f0c)ALL ]

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.Networking.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.Networking.Connectivity.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

 'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\FirewallAPI.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nsi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mswsock.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mfplat.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\avrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

[17:33:10(f0c)INFO]Physical socket created : 7
IP:107.108.72.78

 PORT:5222

 The thread 0x9bc has exited with code 0 (0x0).

 'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dnsapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

  'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\IPHLPAPI.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

  'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winnsi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

  'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\FWPUCLNT.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

 'sample_app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rasadhlp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

 First-chance exception at 0x75F87945 in sample_app.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Platform::COMException ^ at memory location 0x0848EBC0. HRESULT:0x8007274D
```

End of logs

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Call stack before crash (if needed)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 KernelBase.dll!75f87945() Unknown
 [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for KernelBase.dll] 
 > msvcr110d.dll!_CxxThrowException(void * pExceptionObject, const _s__ThrowInfo*      pThrowInfo) Line 152 C++
 ra.dll!Concurrency::unobserved_task_exception::throw_stored_exception() Line 196 C++
 ra.dll!Concurrency::details::_ExceptionHolder::_RethrowUserException() Line 953 C++
 ra.dll!Concurrency::details::_Task_impl_base::_Wait() Line 1444 C++
 ra.dll!Concurrency::task<unsigned char>::get() Line 3019 C++
 ra.dll!Concurrency::task<void>::get() Line 3970 C++
 ra.dll!<lambda_05604c12395ee9f669b724ea276b81ae>::operator()(Concurrency::task<void> previousTask) Line 863 C++
 ra.dll!   std::_Callable_obj<<lambda_05604c12395ee9f669b724ea276b81ae>,0>::_ApplyX<int,Concurrency::t    ask<void> >(Concurrency::task<void> && _V0) Line 431 C++
 ra.dll!    std::_Func_impl<std::_Callable_obj<<lambda_05604c12395ee9f669b724ea276b81ae>,0>,std::alloca  tor<std::_Func_class<int,Concurrency::task<void>,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,st    d::_Nil,std::_Nil>     >,int,Concurrency::task<void>,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>:    :_Do_call(Concurrency::task<void> && _V0) Line 239 C++
  ra.dll!  std::_Func_class<int,Concurrency::task<void>,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_    Nil,std::_Nil>::operator()(Concurrency::task<void> _Vx0) Line 515 C++
ra.dll!Concurrency::task<unsigned   char>::_ContinuationTaskHandle<void,int,<lambda_05604c12395ee9f669b724ea276b81ae>,std::inte    gral_constant<bool,1>,Concurrency::details::_TypeSelectorNoAsync>::_Continue   (std::integral_constant<bool,1> __formal, Concurrency::details::_TypeSelectorNoAsync    __formal) Line 3393 C++
  ra.dll!Concurrency::task<unsigned    char>::_ContinuationTaskHandle<void,int,<lambda_05604c12395ee9f669b724ea276b81ae>,std::inte    gral_constant<bool,1>,Concurrency::details::_TypeSelectorNoAsync>::_Perform() Line     3301 C++
 ra.dll!Concurrency::details::_PPLTaskHandle<int,Concurrency::task<unsig ned   char>::_ContinuationTaskHandle<void,int,<lambda_05604c12395ee9f669b724ea276b81ae>,std::integral_constant<bool,1>,Concurrency::details::_TypeSelectorNoAsync>,Concurrency::details::_Co    ntinuationTaskHandleBase>::operator()() Line 1254 C++
 ra.dll!   Concurrency::details::_UnrealizedChore::_InvokeBridge<Concurrency::details::_PPLTaskHandle<     int,Concurrency::task<unsigned   char>::_ContinuationTaskHandle<void,int,<lambda_05604c12395ee9f669b724ea276b81ae>,std::inte      gral_constant<bool,1>,Concurrency::details::_TypeSelectorNoAsync>,Concurrency::details::_Co     ntinuationTaskHandleBase> >   (Concurrency::details::_PPLTaskHandle<int,Concurrency::task<unsigned    char>::_ContinuationTaskHandle<void,int,<lambda_05604c12395ee9f669b724ea276b81ae>,std::inte   gral_constant<bool,1>,Concurrency::details::_TypeSelectorNoAsync>,Concurrency::details::_Co     ntinuationTaskHandleBase> * _PChore) Line 4464 C++
  msvcr110d.dll!Concurrency::details::_UnrealizedChore::_UnstructuredChoreWrapper   (Concurrency::details::_UnrealizedChore * pChore) Line 293 C++
   msvcr110d.dll!Concurrency::details::_UnrealizedChore::_Invoke() Line 4419 C++
  msvcr110d.dll!Concurrency::details::WorkItem::Invoke() Line 172 C++
  msvcr110d.dll!Concurrency::details::InternalContextBase::ExecuteChoreInline   (Concurrency::details::WorkItem * pWork) Line 1605 C++
  msvcr110d.dll!Concurrency::details::InternalContextBase::Dispatch(Concurrency::DispatchState * pDispatchState) Line 1719 C++
  msvcr110d.dll!Concurrency::details::FreeThreadProxy::Dispatch() Line 197 C++
  msvcr110d.dll!Concurrency::details::ThreadProxy::ThreadProxyMain(void * lpParameter)    Line 171 C++
  kernel32.dll!76b583db() Unknown
   ntdll.dll!77199a3f() Unknown
    ntdll.dll!77199a12() Unknown
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please advise

Comment: can you tell more about how you are trying to connect?

Comment: My application is trying to connect to the XMPP server through this service daemon server(acts like a intermediate proxy server)

Comment: You said: `the connection doesn't happen.` Please explain. Any errors or messages?

Comment: @Justin Skiles  I have attached the logs. Please check

Comment: @faezshingeri The `HRESULT` at the end of your log `(HRESULT:0x8007274D)` indicates: `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problems with WCF. As I know Windows Store apps can not communicate with local services over HTTP.

But Fiddler has a awesome tool for that. This solved my problem.

Check this out:
http://blog.virtew.com/2012/08/13/using-fiddler-in-a-windows-8-metro-style-app/

Comment: how exactly did you get it done.? i mean what were the settings you had to do to let the local traffic go through the fiddler.As of now i selected my app on the loopback exemption utility list so that its traffic gets captured locally, but it didn't happen.

Comment: I have exempted the loopback restrictions for the app using this command too "CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt –c"

Comment: CheckNetIsolation.exe does the same thing..so if that does not help then the cause of the problem is something else

Comment: But if the problem was something else, even remotely the application should not work right? When i run the server and the app in separate PC, login is happening succeefully.